# A fast algorithm to retrieve M distinct random values from an array of N values

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Recently I was offered to solve the following task (with C++).

*Write a function which retrieves M distinct random values from N values.*

Prerequisites:

- the input array of N values is not necessarily sorted;
- the input array of N values may contain duplicates.

The thing which made me ask for a solution is that I was said that it is possible to implement the algorithm which would have complexity O(M). To me this sounds insane and I haven't managed to find anything at least close to O(M).

Is it even possible to write the algorithm with such small complexity? If no, what complexity can I achieve at all? I would also like to see examples (not necessarily with C++).

Comment: Counterexample: say, all N values are the same. To sample two distinct numbers (or, in this case, to say it isn't possible), we'll need to check all N numbers. So, at least the worst case is O(N).

Comment: @Marat this is what I was thinking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Marat pointed out, this is impossible in general.  The worst case is `O(N)`.

If we want all subsets of `M` elements to be equally likely, you can do it in average time `O(N)` by simply keeping a hash of seen values, and then passing them as we first see them into a [reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) algorithm.  (Note, in practice hashes operate in `O(1)` time, but their theoretical worst case is `O(N)`.)

If we don't care about equally likely, we can stop when you get `M` elements.  The probability of including an element will be directly correlated with its frequency.  This is on average a `O(N)` algorithm.  But if we stipulate that the most common element is `O(K)` then this should finish in time `O(K*M)`.  Alternately if we have `Omega(N)` distinct values (`Omega` is the lower bound version of big-O), then this will finish in average time `O(M)`.

The last requires explanation.  If there are `N0` distinct values, then there are two cases.  If `M < 2 * N0` then the expected waiting time to the next new value is never more than `N0 / (2*N)` (that's a bound on the waiting time for the very last after we've taken the first `M-1`).  But otherwise we know that `M = Omega(N)` and we already know that we can examine the whole set in time `O(N) = O(M)`.  Either way we get our desired average time bound.

Comment: Could you modify the reservoir sampling algorithm to store the selected values in a hash set and, if a selected item turns out to be a duplicate, select the *next* item? But we still run into pathological cases. Hard to see how this can be done without eliminating the duplicates up front.

Comment: @JimMischel I didn't find a reasonable alternative to eliminating the duplicates up front.